# How to use multiple classes with ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a layer with ng-class, and I need to use *user.status* with ng-class. and I have another class that I want to bind on the same layer.

```
<div ng-class="user.status, 'locked':(user.active === '0')">
```

but whats the correct way of doing this? somehow it does not work.

Comment: Bad title. you could change it to a full question or at least a short description to your question.

Comment: yes, you right! I have changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to use `class` and `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-class="{'locked':(user.active === '0')}" class="{{user.status}}">
```

---

UPDATE

This should work without interpolation:

```
<div ng-class="{user.status: true, 'locked':(user.active === '0')}">
```

Comment: Need to check, but *maybe* putting what you have in brackets should work: `<div ng-class="{user.status, 'locked':(user.active === '0')}">`

Comment: yes but I have alot of users, and interpolating adds many watchers on the page. I am trying to do it in ng-class. I actually use bindonce which can be called sameway like ng-class

Comment: I will check it shomz

Comment: no it does not work <div ng-class="{user.status, 'locked':(user.active === '0')}">

Comment: Well, ng-class also uses watcher, I'm not sure about the performance, but you shouldn't be able to see the difference. I thought `<div ng-class="{user.status: true, 'locked':(user.active === '0')}">` might also work, but probably not without another interpolation.

Comment: awesome, let me test quick

Comment: Great, I have updated my answer, but thought it might not work without interpolation, so I removed it. You're welcome, glad I could help!